# Wrong File Error Resize Image Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, image-resize

I just migrated from `Magento 1.9.3.8` to `Magento 2.3.4`, then i copied the image from `Magento 1.9` media to Magento 2 media, i noticed product images still not showing in my Magento 2 frontend, then i run:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

[image]

> Wrong file
>
> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

I already clean the cache , delete the cache file , reindex, but still same error

**Updated**

i've fixed the libpng error by running, but the wrong file error still exists

```
find pub/media -type f -iname '*.png' -exec pngcrush -ow -rem allb -reduce {} \;
```

When i look up the file that causes this error, turns out the file does not exist

Comment: Have you checked this https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/libpng-warning-iCCP-known-incorrect-sRGB-profile/td-p/127379

Comment: @KishorThummar yes but there's no `Wrong file` issue mentioned there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's related to migration in general, but to how your original images are generated
Try [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile) it should work for you

As for **Wrong file** exception, it's thrown in

> vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:64

```
if (!$filename || filesize($filename) === 0) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Wrong file');
    }
```

So I suggest you check that the actual file is not empty

Comment: i already fixed the libpng problem , but the wrong file problem still exist

Comment: Hey @jojo
I've checked the code and this error is thrown in vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:64
It's thrown when the filesize is equals 0 or there's no filename. I suggest you find the file in your screenshot and validate that it's not empty. Also you have masked file name - so can't tell for sure, but you might be using unsupported symbols in file name

Comment: i've tried to open the file , turns out the file doesn't exist , still need to find a way to bypass this error if the file does not exist

Comment: You can add filesize check in here vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Service/ImageResize.php:186 like `if ($this->mediaDirectory->isFile($originalImagePath) && filesize({path_to_the_file}))` so it would just show error without throwing exception which terminates the flow.

Comment: thanks it works fine

Comment: Glad it helped @jojo. You can accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to the solution, it's how to find empty files in pub/media/ folder

```
find ./pub/media/ -type f -empty -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: It helps me to find empty file so i can solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `&& !file_exists($filename)` inside function `validateURLScheme` of `vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` worked for me

```
/**
 * Checks for invalid URL schema if it exists
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return bool
 */
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
    $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
    $url = parse_url($filename);
    if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && 
    !file_exists($filename)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```